# Wilcoxon signed-rank test for count-proportions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, proportion, count-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Let's say that I have several agents able to take action A or B, and I am interested in showing that *taking action A is more likely*. So I have a table that looks something like

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2 |
| 14 | 6 |
| ... | ... |

where each row corresponds to the actions taken by a single agent over the course of the experiment.
The columns are not normally distributed and are paired by rows, so I am using the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

I get different p-values depending on whether I treat the data as counts, or as probabilities/proportions (i.e. normalizing by row sums, so the first row becomes $10/12\approx0.833$, $2/12\approx0.166$).

My question is, which is more appropriate?

Thanks!